# A Question was flagged after editing "Grammar"

Tags: discussion

A question ([The shaders included in "Super Secret Settings" won't turn off!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223530/my-super-secret-settings-wont-turn-off)) was flagged when a certain user deleted the important information that set it apart from the question it was "duplicate of".

The problem is that I realize now that I have no idea how to deal with this. I flagged it for moderater attention, but I fear that this will happen in the future.

Can we prevent this from happening in any way?

Comment: If you feel it is *not* a dupe, you can add a comment explaining why, and the vote to reopen the question

Comment: In this particular case, I'd agree that it's probably not a dupe. I would also immediately close it as unclear after reopening since "the blocks still have a red shadow to it!" doesn't really tell us much about the problem. (Why "still"? Are the block shadows red? Do the blocks have strange afterglow? Is it [this](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZM0_Yej50y8/maxresdefault.jpg)?) Realistically, the user will not come back to clarify this, ever, and I don't see the point in reopening to reclose for another reason.